# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (100)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to execute my dataset with batch size = 100. It works fine with batch size = 1 but with 100, it gives the error as: ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (100).

````
    class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Net, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(100, 1, kernel_size=1)
            self.dropout = nn.Dropout2d()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(16, 1)
            self.hybrid = Hybrid(qiskit.Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), 100, np.pi / 2)
    
        def forward(self, x):
            x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
            x = self.dropout(x)
            x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = self.fc2(x)
            x = self.hybrid(x)
            return torch.cat((x, 1 - x), -1)
    ```
    The sizes of data, label and output where output = model(data) are
    torch.Size([100, 32])
    torch.Size([100])
    torch.Size([1, 2])
    ```
    How to make the size of output same as data size?
````

Comment: What is this 32-component vector representing with respect to the target scalar ground-truth?

Comment: It is the number of features,

Comment: What are you trying to do with your loss (and which loss is that exactly)?

Comment: The size of my training data is (369289,35) while that of test data is (41034,35). I have used conv1D with NLL loss and Adam optimizer. I executed the program with few records and batch size of 1 on cpu perfectly. But now I want to run the entire dataset and this requires GPU. With a batch size of 1, the training loop keeps on processing for hours. So now i want to change the batch size to 100. As a result, the error has popped.

Comment: With a `batch_size > 1`, can you tell me the output shape of `self.hybrid(x)`?

Comment: It is torch.Size([1, 1])

Comment: How come you only have one batch as a result, shouldn't `Hybrid` returns one scalar per batch element?